How do I allow a program started through the command line to receive input from another program?
I have two programs. For simplicity, Program A takes any input from the console and just prints it out. Program B (in C#), is supposed to send input to Program A.
Program A is started from a .bat file, something along the lines of 'start ProgramA.exe'. In Program B, when I attempt to access the Standard Input of Program A: programAProcess.StandardInput I get an error System.InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected
If I had started Program A through Program B, I would typically do something like process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;, but I can't do that with a process that has already been started external to my program.
What can I add to the command to start Program A and be able to access its input from Program B?
Program A:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToLower() == "q")
                break;
            else
                Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}

Program B:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process programA = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProgramA")[0];
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToLower() == "q")
                break;
            else
            {
                if (programA == null)
                    return;
                Console.WriteLine(programA.ProcessName + " : " + programA.ToString());
                StreamWriter inputWriter = programA.StandardInput;

                inputWriter.WriteLine("input");
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you post some code snippets from application A and B on what you currently have?

@Narzard I've edited the question to add simplified version of the programs. Both programs are run in separate console windows. When I input something in Program B, I expect it to be input into Program A. the programA process is correctly set in Program B. The error I receive is from StreamWriter inputWriter = programA.StandardInput;

As another note, assume that I can't modify Program A. I can fully change Program B, and I can change the arguments in the command that's used to start Program A from the command line.

windows has an attach console api where you can attach program b to the running console A's window, but It will not be hooked into the actual stdin of program a. It will just simply print messages from B on the console window of A. Is that an option? Otherwise, you could get creative and use sendKeys to replicate the B inputs and automatically type them onto console A. There is no way to get access to the stdin of an already running program that wasnt started with it though.

Generally, as far as I know, you cannot.
Input/output is not freely attachable from the outside. That is, if the process of program A has been started with a certain stdin (e.g. a console window or a pipe or a file), then it is exclusively attached to that input – another program cannot unilaterally splice something else into that connection, even more so if you still want to retain the original input (it's one-to-one).
There are various workarounds that can be used; e.g. if there is a console window, then that window can be sent input events (e.g. similar to how AHK would) which it'll dutifully forward to the process.
If you're in control of how that process starts in general, you can pre-create a named pipe (\\.\pipe\foo) and redirect input from it when starting, then process B can separately start and open the same pipe.
If you have the necessary permissions over the running process, you could probably attach to it like a debugger and force it to re-open its own stdin from some other source (necessarily closing the original source), e.g. create a named pipe and somehow inject its read end into the other process.

Its worth pointing out, that if you have full control over starting Process A, it would be much easier to simply start it from within Process B so you DO have full access to its input.

@grawity_u1686 So, Program A does have a process window. Presuming I have the process object, how would I send input to the window?
